# Node.JS: How to check if jQuery has loaded

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

I used `npm install jquery`, and I put this bit of code in my `server.js` to check if jQuery exists:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log("Connection " + socket.id + " accepted.");

    // Check if jQuery is loaded
    if (jQuery) {  
        console.log("jQuery loaded!");
    }
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
        console.log('jQuery has not been loaded!');  
    }

});
```

When I run `server.js`, I get `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

Is there a better way to check if jQuery is loaded, or does this message mean that I have not successfully installed jQuery?

**EDIT:**

***client.html***

```
<body>

<script>
    function send() {
        var user_message = $("#message_box").val();
        socket.send(user_message);
    };
</script>

<input id="message_box" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
<button id="sender" onClick='send()'/>Send Message</button>

</body>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery in node.js? There's no DOM to manipulate though is there?

Comment: @JackBauer you need to clarify some your question a little. Where is jQuery isn't working (browser or client)? Where the question code comes from (could be browser as well as node). What are you trying to achieve (jQuery should exists where)?

Comment: @elmigranto Apologies: I want jQuery to exist in my client.html page. In particular, I want to use a jQuery selector to get the contents of a textbox. Socket.IO will then pass the message to server.js, which will then broadcast the message to all connected clients. I am editing my initial post to include some code to this effect.

Comment: That being said, isn't the conventional way of loading packages to store them on the server (through "require" in server.js) and then call them (with <script src=""></script>) in client.html?

Answer (score 4):

That's not web borwser, you should `require` jQuery module and define `jQuery` variable yourself (just like you do with SocketIO).

```
var jQuery = require('jQuery')
```

Checkout [docs](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery) for details.

---

**upd**

Regarding question update.

You do not need to `npm install jquery` for making library work in your HTML pages (since javascript in those will be executed in user's browser, and not Node). What you need to do is include remote script in your HTML-documet like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Embedd jQuery into HTML page to make it available in browser -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // So, browser now knows about jQuery, but don't know about anything in <body>
      // We should wait, untill page will be fully loaded, and only then
      // read html input values, initiate connections, etc.
      $(function() {
        // this code will be executed after DOM is ready
        send();
      });

      // here is your send function
      function send() {
        var user_message = $("#message_box").val();
        socket.send(user_message);
      };
    </script>

  </head>
<!-- ... -->
```

IMO, you should really go through some tutorials on client-side javascript programming (with or without jQuery — doesn't really matter). Then, see some tutorials about working with Node as a backend for your site.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. I don't know how to check if jQuery actually works. I tried referencing it on the client side, and nothing happened, which is why I'm so interested in checking.

Comment: @JackBauer there are [examples](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery#examples) and [tests](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/tree/master/test). If you want to know, whether jQuery is loaded on client-side... Well, it is, since SocketIO is javascript which you include in `head`, right? (Do it after including jQuery to be certain.) Or you can initiate SocketIO-connection inside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: There's no evidence that the client is detecting jQuery. I check for jQuery inside of $(function(){});, and nothing happens.

Comment: @JackBauer So you use jQuery to check whether jQuery works? Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to see if the variable JQuery is there, which in your code, you haven't defined the variable JQuery. JQuery isn't a variable, therefore it won't work.

Comment: Ah ha. I put <code>var jQuery = require('jQuery')</code> at the top of my <code>server.js</code>, and <code>if(jQuery)</code> returns true, but I'm guessing that doesn't actually indicate that I can use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking for window.jQuery, the window should exist so you should get undefined back instead.

I would actually set something else up though maybe something like

```
$(function () {
  Console.log( 'jQuery loaded');
});
```

Then you can respond to that on your server however you need to.

I'm not hugely familiar with socket.io so I suspect there may be a better way, but this would at least give you the info you need.

Comment: Yeah, I get ReferenceError: window is not defined...what does that actually mean?

Comment: Take a look at @elmigranto 's answer, I think he grokked what you were trying to do much better

Answer (score 0):

Using `typeof jQuery == 'undefined'` will not crash if `jQuery` is undefined, so you could just use something like this :

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    console.log('jQuery has not been loaded!');  
}
else {
    console.log('jQuery loaded!');
}
```

Comment: I actually defined it at the top of server.js with jQuery = require('jQuery'). I'm not sure whether my jQuery selectors are actually working, however.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're just trying to make sure you're not sending socket.io data to the web browser until **after** jQuery is loaded and ready on the browser correct? If that is the case, then all you have to do is add the script tag referencing jQuery like normal in the html, and then initialize the socket.io client in `$(document).ready`. Something like the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
            $('#news').append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Timothy-- Should all of my client-side Socket.IO code go in that very document.ready? Thanks!

Comment: It can. I'm not clear on what problem you were trying to solve.